# What are practical differences between `REPLACE` and `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, insert, replace

What I need is to set the values of all the fields of a record with a particular key (the key is composite actually), inserting the record if there is no record with such a key yet.

[`REPLACE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replace.html) seems as meant to do the job, but at the same time its manual page suggests 
[`INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html).

What of them should I better choose and why?

The only "side effect" of `REPLACE` that comes into my mind is that it would increment autoincrement values (fortunately I don't use any) while `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` probably wouldn't. What are the other practical differences to take in mind? In what particular cases can `REPLACE` be preferred over `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` and vice versa?

Comment: INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE does in fact also increment the autoincrement counter. Not for the record being updated, but for the next record inserted. So if the highest ID is 10 and you do a duplicate insert, and then inserts a new unique value, that row' s ID will become 12.

Answer (score 147):

`REPLACE` internally performs a delete and then an insert. This can cause problems if you have a foreign key constraint pointing at that row. In this situation the `REPLACE` could fail or worse: if your foreign key is set to cascade delete, the `REPLACE` will cause rows from other tables to be deleted. This can happen even though the constraint was satisfied both before and after the `REPLACE` operation.

Using `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` avoids this problem and is therefore prefered.

Comment: Good answer, but in the actual case of mine this problem is not going to be met. The chance of collision can though be considered 50/50. What should I choose then? And as `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` looks considerably "better" then in what particular cases can "REPLACE" be a better choice?

Comment: I've done a fair bit of research and as far as I can tell, there is no common reason to use REPLACE instead of INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE.  It's essentially a legacy feature.  Unless there's some particular reason why your code relies on rows being deleted and re-added, with the associated effects on indexes and auto-increment values, there doesn't appear to be any reason to use it.

Comment: On `REPLACE` will update your PK auto-increment value if it does a `DELETE` and `INSERT`. Which is exactly what I want. I do not want the consumer to find the record under the same PK, so they get no rows. When I want them to find it (actual update), I use `UPDATE`

Comment: So the other half of the question: when would you prefer `REPLACE` over `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`? Why would an `INSERT` + `DELETE` ever be preferred over an `UPDATE`?

Answer (score 83):

To answer the question in terms of performance, I did a test using both the methods

*Replace Into involves:*
1.Try insert on the table
2. If 1 fails, delete row and insert new row
*Insert on Duplicate Key Update involves:*
1.Try insert on table
2.If 1 fails, update row
If all the steps involved are inserts, there should be no difference in performance. The speed has to depend on the number of updates involved. Worst case is when all the statements are updates

I have tried both the statements on my InnoDB table involving 62,510 entries (only updates). On camparing speeds:
Replace Into: 77.411 seconds
Insert on Duplicate Key Update: 2.446 seconds

```
Insert on Duplicate Key update is almost 32 times faster.
```

Table Size: 1,249,250 rows with 12 columns on an Amazon m3.medium

Comment: Cool stats, did you try `Insert on Duplicate Key Replace`? Was it slower?

Comment: @radtek you can only write `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`, you can't write `ON DUPLICATE KEY REPLACE`. If you want to update all values of existing row upon duplicate key, you have to write `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE col1=VALUES(col1), col2=VALUES(col2), ...` - you have to list all columns manually.

Comment: I know I was just asking what was faster and looks like update is.

Comment: what is the purpose of `REPLACE` command then if it is so useless and only causes problems? Shouldn't this feature be depreciated then?

Answer (score 14):

When using `REPLACE` instead of `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`, I sometimes observe key locking or deadlock problems when multiple queries arrive quickly for a given key. The atomicity of the latter (in addition to not causing cascade deletes) is all the more reason to use it.

Answer (score 4):

> In what particular cases can REPLACE be preferred over INSERT ... ON
>   DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE and vice versa?

I've just found out the hard way that in the case of tables with a FEDERATED storage engine `INSERT...ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` statements are accepted, but fail (with an Error 1022: Can't write; duplicate key in table...) if a duplicate-key violation occurs - see corresponding bullet point on [this page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/federated-limitations.html) of the MySQL Reference Manual.

Fortunately, I was able to use `REPLACE` instead of `INSERT...ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` within my after insert trigger to achieve the desired outcome of replicating changes to a FEDERATED table.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't list all the columns, I think `REPLACE` will reset any unmentioned columns with their default values in the replaced rows. `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` will leave unmentioned columns unchanged.

Answer (score 2):

Replace seems that it does two operations in the case that the key already exists. Perhaps that implies there is a speed difference between the two?

(INSERT)one update  vs  one delete + one insert(REPLACE)

EDIT: My implication that replace might be slower is actually completely wrong. Well, according to this blog post anyway... http://www.tokutek.com/2010/07/why-insert-on-duplicate-key-update-may-be-slow-by-incurring-disk-seeks/

Answer (score 1):

"It is possible that in the case of a duplicate-key error, a storage engine may perform the REPLACE as an update rather than a delete plus insert, but the semantics are the same."

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replace.html

Answer (score 0):

REPLACE seems to be necessary sometimes because INSERT IGNORE doesn't seem to work with data transformations.

If I do this, I only set largestCityPop to itself:

> INSERT IGNORE INTO largestCities (stateID, largestCityPop, statePop) 
>   SELECT stateID, MAX(city.pop) as largestCityPop, state.pop FROM city
>   JOIN state on city.stateID = state.ID GROUP BY city.stateID ON
>   DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE largestCityPop = largestCityPop

If I do this, I am using the GROUP function improperly:

> INSERT IGNORE INTO largestCities (stateID, largestCityPop, statePop) 
>   SELECT stateID, MAX(city.pop) as largestCityPop, state.pop FROM city
>   JOIN state on city.stateID = state.ID GROUP BY city.stateID ON
>   DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE largestCityPop = MAX(city.pop)

And if I do this, MySQL won't recognize the column name:

> INSERT IGNORE INTO largestCities (stateID, largestCityPop, statePop) 
>   SELECT stateID, MAX(city.pop) as largestCityPop, state.pop FROM city
>   JOIN state on city.stateID = state.ID GROUP BY city.stateID ON
>   DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE largestCityPop = city.largestCityPop

This works, but seems just plain ugly:

> INSERT IGNORE INTO largestCities (stateID, largestCityPop, statePop) 
>   SELECT * FROM (SELECT stateID, MAX(city.pop) as biggestCityPop,
>   state.pop FROM city JOIN state on city.stateID = state.ID GROUP BY
>   city.stateID) x ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE largestCityPop =
>   biggestCityPop

Comment: Beware: `INSERT IGNORE` query will finish successfully (and will issue a warning) if a *foreign constraint fails*! If you want to catch an error like this, better use `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` without `IGNORE`.