# UPDATE Query in Mysql Does not work

Tags: php, mysql

I have face a problem with my UPDATE Query in Mysql-

```
mysql_query( INSERT INTO `cost`  
             SET `cat_id` = '18', `feature_id` = '77', `type_id` = '5', 
                 `cost_from` = '600', `cost_to` = '800'  
             WHERE `type_id` = 5 && `cat_id` = 18 && `feature_id` = 77");
```

`type_id` = 5 is not in my current table where i want to SET my new values.
The result is **Unsuccessful.**

I tried also an UPDATE query for the same

```
mysql_query( Update `cost` 
             SET `cat_id` = '18', `feature_id` = '77', `type_id` = '5', 
                 `cost_from` = '600', `cost_to` = '800' 
             WHERE `type_id` = 5 && `cat_id` = 18 && `feature_id` = 77");
```

What should i do to insert and update values at the same time?

Comment: How do you want to insert and update at the same time? That doesn't makes any sense!

Comment: If i have no filed then it should insert as i know, and if then it update the field.

Comment: @Rizier123, In dynamic programming i need to update a field that is not fixed so if a new filed comes then what to update other field and insert new filed? Thats why i need both the query at the same time.

Comment: @mpranks you are using php, then why not check the dynamic file before update or insert?

Comment: @Rizier123, http://www.plus2net.com/sql_tutorial/sql_insert_set.php

Answer (score 1):

Note:

- You don't use WHERE and SET on an INSERT query.
- Make sure you have a table named `cost` along with the columns `cat_id`, `feature_id`, `cost_from`, `cost_to`, `type_id`.
- You're trying to update the `cost` table columns with the ones you are looking for. Doesn't seem right.
- Your first and second given sample codes have the same format, you just changed the first word, `INSERT` and `UPDATE`. Doesn't work that way.

You can, I think the recommendation of all people that would see your code, create better queries using `mysql_* prepared statements`.

A simple example of an INSERT query would look like this:

```
/* PREPARE YOUR QUERY */
$stmt = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO cost (cat_id, feature_id, type_id, cost_from, cost_to) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)");

/* BIND PARAMETER TO THE QUERY. REPLACE NECESSARY VALUE OR VARIABLE */
$stmt->bind_param('iiiss', $catid,$featureid,$typeid,$costfrom,$costto); 

$stmt->execute(); /* EXECUTE QUERY */
```

A simple example of an UPDATE query:

```
/* PREPARE YOUR QUERY */
$stmt = $con->prepare("UPDATE cost SET cat_id=?, feature_id=?, type_id=?, cost_from=?, cost_to=? WHERE id=?");

/* BIND PARAMETER TO THE QUERY. REPLACE NECESSARY VALUE OR VARIABLE */
$stmt->bind_param('iiissi', $catid,$featureid,$typeid,$costfrom,$costto,$id); 

$stmt->execute(); /* EXECUTE QUERY */
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you cannot use 'set ' with ' insert into'  , and if you want to insert and update queries at the same time, then your best bet is using transaction . (you have to enclose insert and update queries in a transaction) , you cannot enclose both on a single sql statement..

This post might help you 
 [SQL Update,Delete And Insert In Same Time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17647923/sql-update-delete-and-insert-in-same-time])