# Combine Insert, Update and Select in MySQL

Tags: mysql, select, insert

Is there a way to combine an insert, update, and select query into one?

Kind of like in a condition,
if select query, when the condition is true it will go to update and if not it will go to insert.

How can i do this?

Comment: Look up "insert on duplicate key update" in the documentation.

Comment: which scripting language you are using?

Comment: Look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14259249/mysql-insert-or-update-if

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's not possible, in the context of a single SQL statement.

It is possible to combine and INSERT and UPDATE action into a single statement. The `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` statement will basically attempt to INSERT a row, and if that insert results in a "duplicate key" exception, the UPDATE action will be performed instead.

But in terms of a testing some general condition with a SELECT statement, and then running an INSERT or UPDATE depending on the result of the query, the answer is no, MySQL does not have any single statement syntax to support that.

Comment: The INSERT...ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE worked just fine :) THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

STORED PROCEDURE is the ANSWER and IF/ELSE

Comment: is it possible to put if/else condition on a mysql query? sorry for the dumb question, but is it?

Comment: in SELECT only IF or CASE... no IF/ELSE. I was suggesting IF/ELSE in case of stored procs.