# How to make insert or delete?

Tags: mysql

Structure table:

```
id (int primary key)
name (varchar 100)
date(datetime)
```

For insert I use query:

```
INSERT INTO table (name, date) VALUES ('t1','$date');
```

For delete row I use query:

```
DELETE FROM table WHERE name = 't1';
```

I would like want how make 1 query: first insert, if row with it `name` already exist, than delete row, and insert again.

Tell me please how to make it?

Comment: Unless you're bound by some data protection requirement, consider just setting a 'hidden' (or 'active') flag to 1 (or 0). That way you don't have to use DELETE at all, and allows the possibility of 'undoing' a 'DELETE' operation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Create a `UNIQUE` index over your `name` column:

   ```sql
   ALTER TABLE `table` ADD UNIQUE (name);
   ```
2. If you genuinely want to "*delete row and insert again*", then you can use [`REPLACE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/replace.html) instead of `INSERT`.  As documented:

   > [`REPLACE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/replace.html) works exactly like [`INSERT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/insert.html), except that if an old row in the table has the same value as a new row for a `PRIMARY KEY` or a `UNIQUE` index, the old row is deleted before the new row is inserted.

   Therefore, in your case:

   ```sql
   REPLACE INTO `table` (name, date) VALUES ('t1','$date');
   ```

   However, if instead of *deleting* the existing record and then *inserting* a new one you merely want to *update* the existing record, you can use [`INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/insert-on-duplicate.html):

   ```sql
   INSERT INTO `table` (name, date) VALUES ('t1','$date')
   ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE date = VALUES(date);
   ```

   The most material difference is in the treatment of columns for which you do not provide explicit values (such as `id` in your example): `REPLACE` will result in the new record having the default value, whereas `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` will result in the old value being retained.

Comment: Consider this : http://stackoverflow.com/a/9168948/1026199 before using `REPLACE`

Comment: yes, I just do not know how to articulate about duplicate entries. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is use MySQL's [on duplicate update](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) feature.

Can be used like this :

```
INSERT INTO table (name, date) VALUES ('t1','$date')
 ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE name=VALUES(name),dateVALUES(date);
```

Of course for that to happen a dupliate violation must occur.

Answer (score 0):

```
insert into table (name, date) values('t1','$date') on duplicate key update  name=values(name), date=values(date)
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for an update query?

Update will set a value on an already existing row.

```
UPDATE table SET date = '$newdate' WHERE name = 't1';
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is using the mysql methods together with your query. 
If you make the 'name' field unique:

```
id (int primary key)
name (varchar 100) NOT NULL UNIQUE 
date(datetime)
```

And alter the query to:

```
INSERT INTO table 
    (name, date) VALUES ('t1','$date') 
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE date = "$date"
```