# updating the mysql table if query store_num exits

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

Everyone!

I am working on application using php and mysql. Basically, initially, I am inserting the new data entries using html form into the database where store# is my primary key. For now I can not update the existing store# (as its my primary key) and get a message saying "Duplicate entry for store 967 (example)".
 I want to  update the "store" table if entery exists. Here is my code posted below, but I am getting another error message

*Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '['967'],`address`=['500 kipling avenue 1'],`dsm_name`=['n/a'],`phone`=['416-967-' at line 1*

I am not sure if I am using the if conditional at right spot.

```
**$sql = "INSERT INTO `stores`(`store_num`, `address`, `dsm_name`, `phone`, `router_type`, `high_speed_pri`, `dsl_log`, `dsl_pass`, `secondary_conn`, `sec_dsl`, `sec_pass`) VALUES ('$store' , '$address', '$dsm', '$phone', '$router', '$highspeedpr', '$dsllog', '$dslpas', '$secondary_conn' , '$secdsl' , '$sec_pass')";

$mysqli_query = "SELECT * from 'stores' WHERE $store = 'store_num'";

if ($mysqli_query == TRUE){

$sql = "UPDATE `stores`   SET `store_num`=['$store'],`address`=['$address'],`dsm_name`=['$dsm'],`phone`=['$phone'],`router_type`=['$router'],`high_speed_pri`=['$highspeedpr'],`dsl_log`=['$dsllog'],`dsl_pass`=['$dslpas'],`secondary_conn`=['$secondary_conn'],`sec_dsl`=['$secdsl'],`sec_pass`=['$sec_pass'] WHERE 1";

}

if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql)) {
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}
echo "1 record added";

mysqli_close($con);

?>**
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Replace instead of Insert

Since your update statement includes all the same fields as Insert, you can simply use a **[REPLACE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replace.html)** Statement. As stated on the linked documentation:

> REPLACE works exactly like INSERT, except that if an old row in the
>   table has the same value as a new row for a PRIMARY KEY or a UNIQUE
>   index, the old row is deleted before the new row is inserted. See
>   Section 13.2.5, “INSERT Syntax”.

So, changing the code to the following should work:

```
$sql = "REPLACE INTO `stores`(`store_num`, `address`, `dsm_name`, `phone`, `router_type`, `high_speed_pri`, `dsl_log`, `dsl_pass`, `secondary_conn`, `sec_dsl`, `sec_pass`) VALUES ('$store' , '$address', '$dsm', '$phone', '$router', '$highspeedpr', '$dsllog', '$dslpas', '$secondary_conn' , '$secdsl' , '$sec_pass')";
```

### Error Reason

Your problem is with the syntax in the update statement. What is `store_num`, is it a number or a string?

You should change your syntax to not include the square brackets in the actual mysql query.

**If $Store is Number:**

`=['$store'],` to `=$store`

**If $Store is Text:**

`=['$store'],` to `='$store'`

### Final Recommendation

Even better though will be use prepared statements which are also secure and avoid against SQL injection attacks.

Comment: Thank you very much maythesource.com.... I have made it work. I guess I was wrong using the UPDATE Query which I got, actually, from SQL tab under PHPMyAdmin. I copied the sentence and changed the values. Also the store_num was a number. It did work. You made my day. :)

Comment: No problem! I'd suggest you read the following though: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9168948/1688441 . If you have foreign keys referencing store_num with cascade delete you should use Gordon's solution. Otherwise your gold.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this logic with a single query, using `on duplicate key update`.  First, you have to define `store_num` as a unique key, if it is not already a unique or primary key:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX idx_stored_storenum on stores(store_num);
```

Then use this `insert`:

```
INSERT INTO `stores`(`store_num`, `address`, `dsm_name`, `phone`, `router_type`, `high_speed_pri`,
                     `dsl_log`, `dsl_pass`, `secondary_conn`, `sec_dsl`, `sec_pass`
                    )
     VALUES ('$store' , '$address', '$dsm', '$phone', '$router', '$highspeedpr',
             '$dsllog', '$dslpas', '$secondary_conn' , '$secdsl' , '$sec_pass')
     ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE address = values (address),
                             dsm_name = values(dsm_name),
                             . . .
                             sec_pass = values(sec_pass);
```

Your particular problem is the square braces, which MySQL doesn't recognize.