# SQL/JAVA: Upon attempting to save data to tables will not add to tables

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

My code not saving any of the data into the tables. I'm not sure why it isn't though, I fixed the error I posted in the last post. Any reason why it wouldn't? It's no longer giving me any errors. Are the tables I have compatible with the queries? I'm really stuck now.

Here is the code for saving it into the tables:

```
public boolean saveHighScore(Client c) throws SQLException {
long totallvlexp = (long) (c.playerXP[0]) + (c.playerXP[1]) + (c.playerXP[2]) + (c.playerXP[3]) + (c.playerXP[4]) + (c.playerXP[5]) + (c.playerXP[6]) + (c.playerXP[7]) + (c.playerXP[8]) + (c.playerXP[9]) + (c.playerXP[10]) + (c.playerXP[11]) + (c.playerXP[12]) + (c.playerXP[13]) + (c.playerXP[14]) + (c.playerXP[15]) + (c.playerXP[16]) + (c.playerXP[17]) + (c.playerXP[18]) + (c.playerXP[19]) + (c.playerXP[20]); 
int totallevell = (int) (c.getLevelForXP(c.playerXP[0]) + c.getLevelForXP(c.playerXP[1]) + c.getLevelForXP(c.playerXP[2]) + c.getLevelForXP(c.playerXP[3]) + c.getLevelForXP(c.playerXP[4]) + c.getLevelForXP(c.playerXP[5]) + c.getLevelForXP(c.playerXP[6]) + c.getLevelForXP(c.playerXP[7]) + c.getLevelForXP(c.playerXP[8]) + c.getLevelForXP(c.playerXP[9]) + c.getLevelForXP(c.playerXP[10]) + c.getLevelForXP(c.playerXP[11]) + c.getLevelForXP(c.playerXP[12]) + c.getLevelForXP(c.playerXP[13]) + c.getLevelForXP(c.playerXP[14]) + c.getLevelForXP(c.playerXP[15]) + c.getLevelForXP(c.playerXP[16]) + c.getLevelForXP(c.playerXP[17]) + c.getLevelForXP(c.playerXP[18]) + c.getLevelForXP(c.playerXP[19]) + c.getLevelForXP(c.playerXP[20]));
boolean result = true;
String updateSkillsSql = "UPDATE skills"
    + " SET `Attacklvl`=?,"
    + " `Attackxp`=?,"
    + " `Defencelvl`=?,"
    + " `Defencexp`=?,"
    + " `Strengthlvl`=?,"
    + " `Strengthxp`=?,"
    + " `Hitpointslvl`=?,"
    + " `Hitpointsxp`=?,"
    + " `Rangelvl`=?,"
    + " `Rangexp`=?,"
    + " `Prayerlvl`=?,"
    + " `Prayerxp`=?,"
    + " `Magiclvl`=?,"
    + " `Magicxp`=?,"
    + " `Cookinglvl`=?,"
    + " `Cookingxp`=?,"
    + " `Woodcuttinglvl`=?,"
    + " `Woodcuttingxp`=?,"
    + " `Fletchinglvl`=?,"
    + " `Fletchingxp`=?,"
    + " `Fishinglvl`=?,"
    + " `Fishingxp`=?,"
    + " `Firemakinglvl`=?,"
    + " `Firemakingxp`=?,"
    + " `Craftinglvl`=?,"
    + " `Craftingxp`=?,"
    + " `Smithinglvl`=?,"
    + " `Smithingxp`=?,"
    + " `Mininglvl`=?,"
    + " `Miningxp`=?,"
    + " `Herblorelvl`=?,"
    + " `Herblorexp`=?,"
    + " `Agilitylvl`=?,"
    + " `Agilityxp`=?,"
    + " `Thievinglvl`=?,"
    + " `Thievingxp`=?,"
    + " `Slayerlvl`=?,"
    + " `Slayerxp`=?,"
    + " `Farminglvl`=?,"
    + " `Farmingxp`=?,"
    + " `Runecraftlvl`=?,"
    + " `Runecraftxp`=?"
    + " WHERE `playerName`=?";


String updateSkillsoverallSql = "UPDATE skillsoverall"
+ " SET `lvl`=?,"
+ " `xp`=?"
+ " WHERE `playerName`=?";

String updatePlayerRightsSql = "UPDATE playerrights"
+ " SET `rank` = ?"
+ " WHERE `playerName`=?";

try(Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/highscores","root","root")) {
con.setAutoCommit(false);
    try(PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement(updateSkillsSql);PreparedStatement pstmt2 = con.prepareStatement(updateSkillsoverallSql);PreparedStatement pstmt3 = con.prepareStatement(updatePlayerRightsSql);) {
        setParameters(pstmt,
                    c.playerLevel[0], c.playerXP[0],
                    c.playerLevel[1], c.playerXP[1],
                    c.playerLevel[2], c.playerXP[2],
                    c.playerLevel[3], c.playerXP[3],
                    c.playerLevel[4], c.playerXP[4],
                    c.playerLevel[5], c.playerXP[5],
                    c.playerLevel[6], c.playerXP[6],
                    c.playerLevel[7], c.playerXP[7],
                    c.playerLevel[8], c.playerXP[8],
                    c.playerLevel[9], c.playerXP[9],
                    c.playerLevel[10], c.playerXP[10],
                    c.playerLevel[11], c.playerXP[11],
                    c.playerLevel[12], c.playerXP[12],
                    c.playerLevel[13], c.playerXP[13],
                    c.playerLevel[14], c.playerXP[14],
                    c.playerLevel[15], c.playerXP[15],
                    c.playerLevel[16], c.playerXP[16],
                    c.playerLevel[17], c.playerXP[17],
                    c.playerLevel[18], c.playerXP[18],
                    c.playerLevel[19], c.playerXP[19],
                    c.playerLevel[20], c.playerXP[20],
                    c.playerName);

        setParameters(pstmt2,
            totallevell, totallvlexp,
                    c.playerName);
        setParameters(pstmt3,
            c.getPermission().getId(), c.playerName);

        pstmt.executeUpdate();
        pstmt2.executeUpdate();
        pstmt3.executeUpdate();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(String.format("There's a problem when saving the data of  player %s.", c.playerName));
        e.printStackTrace(System.out);
        con.rollback();
        result = false;
    }
    if (result) {
        con.commit();
        con.setAutoCommit(true);
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println(String.format("There's a problem when saving the data of  player %s.", c.playerName));
    e.printStackTrace(System.out);
    result = false;
    }
    return result;
}

private void setParameters(PreparedStatement pstmt, Object ... args) {
    int i = 0;
    try {
        for (Object arg : args) {
            pstmt.setObject(++i, arg);
        }
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Here are the tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `skills` (
`playerName` varchar(15) NOT NULL default '',
`Attacklvl` double default NULL,
`Attackxp` double default NULL,
`Defencelvl` double default NULL,
`Defencexp` double default NULL,
`Strengthlvl` double default NULL,
`Strengthxp` double default NULL,
`Hitpointslvl` double default NULL,
`Hitpointsxp` double default NULL,
`Rangelvl` double default NULL,
`Rangexp` double default NULL,
`Prayerlvl` double default NULL,
`Prayerxp` double default NULL,
`Magiclvl` double default NULL,
`Magicxp` double default NULL,
`Cookinglvl` double default NULL,
`Cookingxp` double default NULL,
`Woodcuttinglvl` double default NULL,
`Woodcuttingxp` double default NULL,
`Fletchinglvl` double default NULL,
`Fletchingxp` double default NULL,
`Fishinglvl` double default NULL,
`Fishingxp` double default NULL,
`Firemakinglvl` double default NULL,
`Firemakingxp` double default NULL,
`Craftinglvl` double default NULL,
`Craftingxp` double default NULL,
`Smithinglvl` double default NULL,
`Smithingxp` double default NULL,
`Mininglvl` double default NULL,
`Miningxp` double default NULL,
`Herblorelvl` double default NULL,
`Herblorexp` double default NULL,
`Agilitylvl` double default NULL,
`Agilityxp` double default NULL,
`Thievinglvl` double default NULL,
`Thievingxp` double default NULL,
`Slayerlvl` double default NULL,
`Slayerxp` double default NULL,
`Farminglvl` double default NULL,
`Farmingxp` double default NULL,
`Runecraftlvl` double default NULL,
`Runecraftxp` double default NULL,
 index (playerName),

constraint fk_playername_rights
foreign key (playername) references players (playername)
on delete restrict
on update restrict 

) ENGINE=MyISAM;
ALTER TABLE skills ADD INDEX idx_playername (playername);

CREATE TABLE `playerrights` (
`playerName` varchar(15) NOT NULL default '',
`rank` int(2) default NULL,
index (playername),

constraint fk_playername_rights
foreign key (playername) references players (playername)
on delete restrict
on update restrict 

) ENGINE=MyISAM;
ALTER TABLE playerrights ADD INDEX idx_playername (playername);

CREATE TABLE `skillsoverall` (
`playerName` varchar(15) NOT NULL default '',
`lvl` int(11) default NULL,
`xp` BIGINT(11) default NULL,
index (playername),

constraint fk_playername_rights
foreign key (playername) references players (playername)
on delete restrict
on update restrict 

) ENGINE=MyISAM;
ALTER TABLE skillsoverall ADD INDEX idx_playerName (playerName);
```

Comment: Do you ever INSERT records to be updated?

Comment: I was under the impression that committing would do that, no?

Comment: @Joliquine4 SQL `update` works with records that already _exist_. You need `insert` to create the initial records.

Comment: Is there a good way to do INSERT the first save and then use update thereafter or do I need to make a java variable store a boolean and keep track of it for each user? @GriffeyDog

Comment: If you are using MySQL (and I am not familiar with it myself), it looks like it has some special statements/syntax you could try. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9168928/what-are-practical-differences-between-replace-and-insert-on-duplicate-ke).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<sup>Turning comments into an answer.</sup>

You probably want/need to change your prepared statement to [INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html).
However, for this to work, you need a `PRIMARY KEY` / `UNIQUE` index. As long as the auxiliary tables do not hold more than maximum a single entry per person, the **playerName** column will satisfy this requirement. (Though a numeric ID might be the better choice in the long run...)

For a simple example, see [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b3ef5/1).
Or check this [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2cdac/1), which is closer to your problem domain. Please note in particular only one record to exist in **Skills** despite two `INSERT`s.

Please comment, if and as this requires adjustment / further detail.

Comment: I managed to get it to save to a database but it always saves as INSERT and never as UPDATE so I end up with several duplicate entries. I am having trouble implementing both PK/UNIQUE in conjunction with FK.

Comment: With no appropriate `PRIMARY KEY` / `UNIQUE` index, the `INSERT` has nothing to check against. Did you arrange the keys as in this answer's Fiddle? Keeping in mind "Important: The inline REFERENCES specifications where the references are defined as part of the column specification are silently ignored. MySQL only accepts REFERENCES clauses defined as part of a separate FOREIGN KEY specification." from [ALTER TABLE Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/alter-table.html)

Comment: Foreign keys are just a means to enforce referential integrity. Don't see them as required for `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`. See this [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7c5c66/1) - still just one record in **Skills**.

Comment: It is now working with `playerName` set to UNIQUE. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any issue with your code after review. However I have a major suggestion that I feel will fix your problem.

Before you attempt to update the table in your code - Print the SQL that is not working. In your case, I believe it is updateSkillsSql.

```
System.out.println(updateSkillsSql);
```

Next, copy and paste the query exactly as it printed into an SQL console currently connected and using your database. Check the SQL for errors if any are returned.

I found that 99% of the time when attempting to write queries in other languages (e.g. PHP, Java) I was able to debug the problem signicifiantly faster when applying it directly through an SQL console. Usually it ended up being missing quotes, or a space where I did not expect one to be.

**If you do this** - Post the results both of the query and the results from running it in SQL. I'll update my answer with further details if you are unable to solve the problem.

Comment: Thank you for the help but I've discovered, with the help of comments, that my problem was simply that I had not used INSERT before UPDATE but now I have a new problem; I don't know how to syntactically use INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE.

Comment: @Joliquine4 Which part of [INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) do you need a hand with? - You seem to lack a `PRIMARY KEY` / `UNIQUE` index, though...

Comment: @Abecee I had a PRIMARY KEY but changed to a foreign key because each of my tables are just different types of data being saved for the same person. I do not know what to make UNIQUE. I was unable to find an example of INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE that used SET and I don't know how it will affect my PreparedStatement's.

Comment: @Joliquine4 The prepared statement does need to hold that exact statement. This statement in turn requires a `PRIMARY KEY` / `UNIQUE` index. For an example see [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/415dc0/1). If the auxiliary tables do hold just/maximum one record per person, the `FOREIGN KEY` should still be unique.

Comment: @Abecee "should" as in I should make them unique or "should" as in it should be unique as it is

Comment: @Joliquine4 As long as there is maximum one record per person in that table, the person column has no duplicates - in other words is *unique*. BTW: I'd usually suggest to use a numeric ID instead of a (user selected) name for keys...