# Using variables with REPLACE

Tags: sql, sql-server, replace, sql-update

SQL 2012
How do I use a variable in the second argument in a replace statement.
e.g:

```
declare @new nchar (10)
declare @old nchar (10)

set @new = 'ABC'
set @old = 'DEF'

update table
set value = REPLACE (column,@old,@new) 
where .....
```

This runs, doesn't produce any errors, but doesn't update anything either.

if I ditch the @old variable and replace it with a value such as

```
set value = REPLACE (column,'DEF',@new)
```

then it works fine.

Comment: I got around the issue by putting the SQL above into a stored procedure, where it works fine.  I tried Udhaya's example and it works fine in a select, but not in an update, it gave an error about a stored procedure which led me to the result.

Answer (score 0):

See thread here: [What are practical differences between `REPLACE` and `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9168928/what-are-practical-differences-between-replace-and-insert-on-duplicate-ke)

Marks answer maybe your issue:

REPLACE internally performs a delete and then an insert. This can cause problems if you have a foreign key constraint pointing at that row. In this situation the REPLACE could fail or worse: if your foreign key is set to cascade delete, the REPLACE will cause rows from other tables to be deleted. This can happen even though the constraint was satisfied both before and after the REPLACE operation.

Using INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE avoids this problem and is therefore prefered.

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @new varchar(50)
declare @old varchar(50)
declare @query varchar(50)

set @new = 'ABCD'
set @old = '1234'

set @query='select replace(''1234EFGH'','''+@old+''','''+@new+''')'

exec (@query)
```