# Is it faster to insert duplicate value in unique column or first check is it already inserted

Tags: php, mysql

I have a unique column in my table that is some long string `id` generated by app.

Now, is it faster that I just use `INSERT` and if that `id` already exists in the table nothing will happen, or is it better that I first check with `SELECT` is that `id` already in the table and if it isn't, then I insert it?

Comment: Or even better, make it auto_increment and just have MySQL do it for you

Comment: Too many possible variables to answer generally. You should performance test with your schema and data.

Comment: ...not to mention unclear, too broad and possibly opinion-based.

Comment: Why on earth did someone upvote this. This question does not fit the rules of the site

Comment: @IsThisJavascript I had that very same thought myself.

Comment: The context of what you're doing could be a deciding factor too.  If the id does already exist, do you want to know the information that was already inserted?  If so, then you'd probably want to `SELECT` first.  If the id does already exist, do you want to `UPDATE` the existing record? If so, then you'd probably want to `INSERT INTO ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`.  You're lacking a lot of helpful information here.

Comment: @verhie I already have auto_increment column. This is another id generated by app, it's a long string.

Comment: That's not far for being an answer @PatrickQ I had that very same thought earlier and was going to hammer it with something similar but that stood to get contested, so I just voted as being too broad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All things being equal, I would expect a simple insert to be faster if the row does not exist, since you are performing two statements otherwise - a check and insert.   The downside is that if the row does exist, your call will throw an error that you then have to handle.

Depending on the behavior you want, you have a couple of options:

Check if existing, as you mentioned.  This is good if you don't want to change anything on the existing record with the new information.  Then handle your errors so they don't get pushed up the call.

INSERT IGNORE will ignore any duplicate key errors; it will also ignore any other errors, so I would advise against it in general.

REPLACE performs a basic UPSERT style command - Inserts if no duplicate found, updates if duplicate found.  The "cost" is you always write the full record to the database, even if nothing is changed.

INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE UPDATE works a bit like REPLACE, but it allows you to specify which values you want to update, potentially even adding different information instead of the inserted values (should you need that).

There are some key differences between REPLACE and ON DUPLICATE, and I suggest you take a look at this question for more lengthy breakdowns:  [What are practical differences between `REPLACE` and `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9168928/what-are-practical-differences-between-replace-and-insert-on-duplicate-ke#9168948)