# INSERT...ON DUPLICATE KEY when updating a table

Tags: mysql, sql

Is there a way to do something like the following in mysql:

```
INSERT INTO new_table 
    SELECT * 
    FROM old_table 
    WHERE country='us' **ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE**
```

Or, would I need to run multiple queries to accomplish this (or possibly just write out the full sql command with all the columns to update, etc.)?

Comment: What do you want to update if there's a duplicate key?

Comment: @Nick -- every field. The equivalent of doing a `delete...insert`

Comment: Just use [`REPLACE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/replace.html)

Comment: That's correct, but see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9168928/what-are-practical-differences-between-replace-and-insert-on-duplicate-ke for some caveats.

Comment: @Nick -- awesome, I'd actually never heard of that command before -- thank you!

Comment: @Nick seems to screw up primary keys when I do `select *`...converts auto-incrementing ID field into unsigned int, default=0, so I think that's a valid option.

Comment: @Barmar thanks for pointing that out -- yea I tried it and it seemed to modify some of the integrity fields...anyways I ended up using the delete...create / insert...on duplicate key update approach. Is `REPLACE` a deprecated feature or something of mysql?

Comment: It's a MySQL extension. It says that in the second paragraph of the documentation that Nick linked to.

Comment: @David542 `REPLACE` shouldn't change your structure...

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` like following. It will check duplicate based on the PK of new_table

```
INSERT INTO new_table 
(column1,column2 ....)
SELECT value5,value6 from old_table
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
column1=column5,column2=column6;
```